# Save docker output file in workdir

Tags: python, docker

I am a newby in `docker`
My Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install numpy
RUN pip install pandas
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

And in `app.py` I have a line

```
pd.DataFrame(predictions, columns=['predictions']).to_csv('output.csv')
```

I build and run the image, that's ok but I can not to save this dataframe in my work directory. How to change `Dockerfile` so that I can do it?

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? Do you need the output on your host machine? Or is `output.csv` not being created in `/app` at all?

Comment: I need the output on my host machine. The file is created

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best way to get `output.csv` out of the container onto your host machine is using a volume. Volumes are storage paths that can be shared between host and container, much like shared folders for VMs.

In your case:

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/volume:/app your_image
```

You should then find everything from the container's `/app` path in your working directory under `./volume`.

Comment: It looks like `/app` is not empty, from to the `COPY` instruction in the Dockerfile. The original contents of `/app` would get hidden when the volume is mounted this way. Using any other path to mount the volume instead of `/app` should be fine in this case.

Comment: @Proyag can I delete `COPY` or change `WORKDIR` in Dockerfile?

Comment: I agree, @Proyag. @Edward, you could change your Python code to save your CSV somewhere else, e.g. `/home/your_user/output.csv`. Then you would change the volume definition to `-v $(pwd)/volume:/home/your_user`.

Comment: I use `docker run --rm -v $(pwd)/volume:/e/test my_image` It works but the output is not saved. If I channge in `app.py` `to_csv('/e/test/output.csv') I get error

Comment: `No such file or directory`

Comment: In local it works `to_csv('E:\\test/output.csv')` and the file is saved but this path is not correct for `docker`

Comment: I see. You have to choose a path that exists _inside_ your container, e.g. `/e/test` doesn't seem to exist when you run your Python script. Either choose another path, or add `RUN mkdir -p /e/test` to your Dockerfile. Let me add that it doesn't matter whether the path in the container reflects those on your machine.